# Atom block-select add-on completely missing?

Tags: atom-editor

I had to reinstall Atom and I wanted to install the `block-select` add-on. After clicking on the install button, this error appears:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://www.atom.io/api/packages/block-select/versions/1.0.0/tarball
```

I wanted to report that issue, but the whole GitHub repository is missing too, because this link just returns an 404 https://github.com/radonlab/atom-block-select/

This shouldn't be dependant on the version of atom, but this happens in 1.49 and 1.50

So how can I install `block-select`, what happened to block-select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an equivalent package called `sublime-style-column-selection` with 818,425 downloads:

https://atom.io/packages/sublime-style-column-selection

---

**Notes:**

1. It seems to get stuck installing, but it downloads eventually. The "Install" button might still say "Install" even after it finishes downloading and installing. Check your Packages menu after an attempt.
2. This package uses the `Alt` key. This collides with `Alt`'s default behavior of selecting the menu bar.

**Solution 1: Override this default behavior:**

`Menu bar --> File --> Keymap...`

Add this to keymap.cson:

```
'.platform-win32, .platform-linux':
  'alt': 'abort!'
```

**Solution 2: Change the key to something else:**

`Menu bar --> File --> Settings --> Packages --> sublime-style-column-selection --> Select Key`

[image]

Comment: This looks good but I wasn't able to install it. I let it download something like two hours and it was not installed

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar experience, but it ended up downloading for me; even though the button still said "Install". Not sure if it's an Atom problem or the package's problem. You could download it from github and install it manually: https://github.com/bigfive/atom-sublime-select

Comment: I checked the package menu and it was actually installed and it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

seems like they deleted the repository, try installing a different one will be the only option

Comment: Is there maybe a mirror of these files somewhere?

Comment: I think he probably changed the visibility to private for some reason